# Remove Final 7 Characters from String in Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, substr

I am trying to remove the final 7 characters from a string in PHP before writing it as a result into a table.  When I create the Mysql query in Navicat I get the desired string, but I cannot move this into PHP and make it work.  Here is the working Mysql query (in Navicat):

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(ssp_subjects.uid, 1, LENGTH(ssp_subjects.uid) -7),
ssp_subjects.namefirst,
ssp_subjects.namelast,
ssp_subjects.imageactual,
ssp_subjects.accesscode,
ssp_subjects.correction,
ssp_subjects.correctiondate
FROM
ssp_subjects
WHERE
ssp_subjects.correction = 1
```

Returns:

CCU-SOC-14-05-31-A  KYLE    O'CONNOR    29  GFKDPFLM3F  1   2017-06-20 09:14:39

(This is correct, as it trimmed the final 7 characters from the end of the UID.)

In PHP I am trying to build a similar table, but I can't seem to write the SUBSTRING statement correctly.  This is how I am building the table in PHP:

```
     $sql = "SELECT
    ssp_subjects.correctiondate,
    ssp_subjects.namelast,
    ssp_subjects.namefirst,
    ssp_subjects.imageactual,
    ssp_subjects.accesscode,
    ssp_subjects.uid
    FROM
        ssp_subjects
    WHERE
        ssp_subjects.correction = 1";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Date</th><th>Job Name</th><th>Team Number</th><th>Type</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Access Code</th><th>Sequence</th><th>Card</th><th>Image</th><th>UID</th><th>Order</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$row["correctiondate"]."</td>
        <td><p>Corrections</p></td>
        <td><p>10</p></td>
        <td><p>Player</p></td>
        <td>".$row["namelast"]." </td>
        <td>".$row["namefirst"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["accesscode"]." </td>
        <td><p>1000</p></td>
        <td>".$row["imageactual"]." </td>
        <td> ".$row["uid"]." </td>
        <td><p>1x1</p></td>
        </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

When I try to add SUBSTR in PHP it returns an "Undefined Index:uid" error, instead of the trimmed string.

```
$sql = "SELECT
    ssp_subjects.correctiondate,
    ssp_subjects.namelast,
    ssp_subjects.namefirst,
    ssp_subjects.imageactual,
    ssp_subjects.accesscode,
    SUBSTRING(ssp_subjects.uid, 1, LENGTH(ssp_subjects.uid) -7)
FROM
    ssp_subjects
WHERE
    ssp_subjects.correction = 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `substr($string,-7)`

Comment: I'm fairly certain that same SQL will work in your query. Why do it in PHP?

Comment: I am using PHP because I need to create a process that can be replicated by our lab techs.  Our internal database is written in PHP.  The end goal is to create a table that can be "downloaded" probably via CSV.  I have just started with my attempt to build the table.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am asking the question wrong.  I apologize for being a noob.  I have been trying to solve this problem on my own for a couple of days.  My apologies, but I don't have anyone else I can ask. I am trying to remove the last 7 characters in the table created by PHP, but I cannot figure out how to implement the solution provided "substr($string,-7)".  I will try to figure it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The code to remove the last 7 characters from a string in PHP is

`$string = substr($string, 0, -7);`